# How to add basic grids to GoogleMap Api v2

Tags: android, android-maps-v2

I would like to add the **basic grids** to my GoogleMap that use to be on maps.
I read the docs but didnt found anything that could help, maybe the **TileOverlay** or **GroundOverlay** can do the trick, but i didnt found any examples or tutorials, not even in the official samples.

Can anybody suggest me some ways that could work ?

**E D I T :**

Yes i would like gridlines like this:

[image]

Comment: Do you mean grid lines? I'd suggest making a screenshot of empty map, editing in your favourite version of paint app and posting here. `A picture is worth a thousand words.`

Comment: You are right ill do it soon i will edit my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like I have a code that does exactly that. I used it only for debugging, but here it is: [DebugHelper.java](http://code.google.com/p/android-maps-extensions/source/browse/android-maps-extensions/src/pl/mg6/android/maps/extensions/impl/DebugHelper.java).

[image: Demo]

Some notes:

- you will also have to copy [SphericalMercator.java](http://code.google.com/p/android-maps-extensions/source/browse/android-maps-extensions/src/pl/mg6/android/maps/extensions/utils/SphericalMercator.java)
- change `IGoogleMap` to original `GoogleMap` and `IProjection` to `Projection`
- `clusterSize` parameter is in degrees, so you will have to change it depending on the zoom
- finally: call `drawDebugGrid` in `onCameraChange`.

If you want to see it in action, you may run the demo of [Android Maps Extensions](http://code.google.com/p/android-maps-extensions/). The only change you need to make to see grid is setting DEBUG_GRID to true on one of the first lines in [GridClusteringStrategy.java](http://code.google.com/p/android-maps-extensions/source/browse/android-maps-extensions/src/pl/mg6/android/maps/extensions/impl/GridClusteringStrategy.java).

Comment: Is there a way to add a grid of 2 x 2 km starting from specific location. Any help will be appreciated