# Custom overlay in google maps area clicked then zoom in

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

So I tried to draw grid line on my map and I found a good example on google api documentation here : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/maptype-base

it works , now I have another problem in every area or rectangle which built by grid line, I want them to have a listener on click event and then zoom to area that has been clicked. I have tried like this

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function (e) {
    var latLng = e.latLng;
    map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(latLng.lat(), latLng.lng()));
    map.setZoom(17);
});
```

it works either, but as you can see the latitude and longitude are the exact location where the cursor / pointer clicked, it's not in the middle of the rectangle or area it means the map after zoomed in is wrong. Could anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is because you are using the overlay(as your grid line), when using the tile overlay Google Maps API breaks up the imagery at each zoom level into a set of square map tiles arranged in a grid. When a map moves to a new location, or to a new zoom level, the Maps API determines which tiles are needed and translates that information into a set of tiles to retrieve.

For example each zoom level increases the magnification by a factor of two. So, at zoom level 1 the map will be rendered as a 2x2 grid of tiles. At zoom level 2, it's a 4x4 grid. At zoom level 3, it's an 8x8 grid, and so on.

So when you zoom in, the coordinates that you click is not always in the middle because tile overlay is not set because of your coordinate.
Check this [page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/tileoverlay#coordinates) for more information about overlay.

You can also check this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16211783/how-to-add-basic-grids-to-googlemap-api-v2) for more information.