# Creating a Square grid on the google maps API given the coordinates of the 4 points

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I am new to android studio and I am trying to build a maps-based application.One of the functionalities of the app is to build a square grid on the map given the (latitude,longitude) of the 4 points on the map.Upon research on this topic most of the answers I have found Creates a square grid on the entire map which is not required.Any help with regards to this is deeply appreciated.

Link to the question similar to this:

[Add static square grids using google map api in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48834248/add-static-square-grids-using-google-map-api-in-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Polyline](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Polyline) to draw rectangle on GoogleMap.

Sample Code:

```
// Instantiates a new Polyline object and adds points to define a rectangle
PolylineOptions rectOptions = new PolylineOptions()
    .add(new LatLng(37.35, -122.0))
    .add(new LatLng(37.45, -122.0))  // North of the previous point, but at the same longitude
    .add(new LatLng(37.45, -122.2))  // Same latitude, and 30km to the west
    .add(new LatLng(37.35, -122.2))  // Same longitude, and 16km to the south
    .add(new LatLng(37.35, -122.0)); // Closes the polyline.

// Get back the mutable Polyline
Polyline polyline = myMap.addPolyline(rectOptions);
```

[Check](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/shapes) this link to draw different shapes.